# Is Guid.ToByteArray() cross-platform?

Tags: c#, .net, guid

I want to store Guids in a database which does not support Guid/uniqueidentifier data type, therefore I convert Guid to byte array using .ToByteArray() method. However, this method converts value in a strage way:

```
11223344-5566-7788-9900-AABBCCDDEEFF
will become
44, 33, 22, 11, 66, 55, 88, 77, 99, 00, AA, BB, CC, DD, EE, FF
```

As I understand, this is because of endian ordering.

I would like to know if this method will return the same result on every platform (86x hardware, 64x hardware, Linux, Windows etc) and there will be no changes in byte order no matter on which platform I run my software.

Comment: I have no idea but why not just store it as a string instead of a byte[] ?

Comment: @RonanThibaudau Storing it as a string will require 38 bytes primary key in the database instead of 16 bytes primary key when storing it as byte array.

Comment: Given that Guids are essentially random (not really), the byte order cannot possibly matter.  The odds that a big-endian machine is going to write a guid are pretty doggone small these days anyway.

Comment: @HansPassant It does matter if you take a string representation of a GUID, convert it to a byte array on one platform, store that byte array somewhere, retrieve the byte array on another platform, convert it back to a string, and expect to see the original string. Which is a perfectly sensible thing to expect.

Comment: Ah you didn't mention you wanted to use it as a PK at all, any reason why you'd want to do that in a DB that doesn't support the guid type? How big is your DB going to be and how relevant is that size? Why not store PK as auto incr int and store the GUID on another field?

Comment: Yes, the order does not matter. However, if I get two different arrays on different platforms I will not find my row later, because the key will be changed.

Comment: @user1613797 True but if you're looking for true interop, storing it as a String allows you to use both `GUID` (Windows) and `UUID` (java) without worrying about conversion issues, byte ordering or anything else. Unless you're talking about billions of rows, the additional storage space is trivial.

Comment: Somebody is going to be inconvenienced.  It is up to decide whether to inconvenience 99% or 1% of the programmers.  You can make a case of 99%, everybody gets this wrong right away so you force them to  pay attention to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your question:

> > I would like to know if this method will return the same result on
> >     every platform (86x hardware, 64x hardware, Linux, Windows etc)

Yes **it will be same** for all the platforms.

> > However, this method converts value in a strage way:

The order returned from `ToByteArray` would be different from string representation.

See: [Guid.ToByteArray Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tobytearray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Note that the **order of bytes in the returned byte array is
>   different** from the string representation of a Guid value. The order
>   of the beginning four-byte group and the next two two-byte groups is
>   reversed, whereas the order of the last two-byte group and the closing
>   six-byte group is the same.

Comment: In paticular, different from the string representation *but still well-specified*, and not platform-specific.

Comment: @ava: I don't *think* so, but the documentation could certainly be clearer.

Comment: @JonSkeet Doesn't the order from `ToByteArray` depend on the endianness of the machine? (The [remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tobytearray(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) seem to suggest it does not, but I cannot see why the bytes would be intentionally ordered in little endian.)

Comment: @ava: Deleting your previous comment and then adding another one after I've replied doesn't really help anyone trying to read it. Again, I don't *think* it does, but I don't have an easy way to check right now.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm sorry, I wanted to add to the question and was out of editing time. I refreshed before deleting to make sure you hadn't answered already, but it seems you were simply too quick.